# PHP - Messaging inbox system

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a messaging inbox system. Users create message threads directed at another user. It will work as follows:

1. Message threads you receive appear in your inbox.
2. Message threads you create also appear in your inbox.
3. Message threads you delete are only deleted from your own inbox.

I have the following fields in my `message_thread` table:

- id
- from_user_id
- to_user_id
- subject
- deleted
- updated_at

I have managed to implement 1 and 2 using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM message_thread mt
WHERE ((mt.from_user_id = 1 OR mt.to_user_id = 1) AND mt.deleted = 0)
ORDER BY mt.updated_at DESC
```

I am trying to figure out a way of implementing 3.

I assume new columns will need to be introduced (`from_user_deleted` and `to_user_deleted`). Is it possible to retrieve the correct resultset by extending the query or will this need to be done in the server side script (currently using PHP)?

EDIT: If user A deletes a thread and then user B sends a reply to that thread, it should re-appear in user A's inbox.

Comment: I did the same some time ago and you cannot solve this without another table or flags for each message. I created one table to contain the message prototypes, sender and receiver and one table to overwrite status columns like is_read, is_deleted and so on and I fetch the options from the second table for the current user, if its deleted its not displayed, if its marked unread its displayed in bold and so on. If the entry does not exist in second table I assume standard values because it was never saved like: (unread, not deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by adding a new table:

`message_thread_status`

- message_thread_id (FK)
- user_id (FK)
- deleted (default 0)

When a `message_thread` is created, it creates two entries in the `message_thread_status` table (one for each user in the message thread).

I then just need to find the record for the current user in the `message_thread_status` table and add in a condition to check for the value of `deleted`.

New query:

```
SELECT
     * FROM message_thread mt

LEFT OUTER JOIN
     message_thread_status mts ON mts.message_thread_id = mt.id

WHERE
    ((mt.from_user_id = 1 OR mt.to_user_id = 1)
    AND (mts.user_id = 1 AND mts.deleted = 0))

ORDER BY
    mt.updated_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

1.You can add new field as **status**

2.Status

```
    1 = from_user_deleted
    2 = to_user_deleted
```

Then **Query**

```
SELECT * FROM message_thread mt
WHERE ((mt.from_user_id = 1 OR mt.to_user_id = 1) AND mt.deleted = 0 AND mt.status<>2)
ORDER BY mt.updated_at DESC
```

Comment: That doesn't work.. I set status to 1 and it still appears in both users inboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In plain english:

Where 
  ( The message is to you 
    OR
       ( the message is from you 
          AND 
          the message is not deleted )
    )